# wifi worked until i rebooted

Tags: wireless

EDIT: issue fixed, thanks for the help

So i'm pretty new to Ubuntu.
I installed Ubuntu on my laptop a week ago (dual boot with win 8.1) and I think it's great.
However i'm having a problem with my wifi. It doesn't show any connections (it did until i rebooted).

The last 3 days whent something like this:
First it didn't work at home or on work network. 
Then it suddenly worked at home but not on work network. 
A day later it worked on both networks. 
Then i rebooted and it stopped working on either.

I can provide logs or whatever is needed (if you tell me how to generate them).

I suspect it's because my wireless card is turned off but i'm not sure.

Comment: Please add to your post those command results :
`sudo ifconfig -a`
`sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: added ifconfig cmd output to original post. restart cmd doesnt seem to do anything.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lsusb&&lspci` so we can see what brand of WiFi adapter you have?. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question. 
Welcome

Comment: i added it to the original post

Comment: You edited the question with fixed, but where is the right answer?!

Comment: as this was 9 years ago, Im not 100% sure. I think I found a cli command somewhere that fixed it for me. But I wouldn't be able to tell you what or where. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

On my compaq laptop, celeron processor,  broadcom wifi, with linux mint 17.2 pushing the wifi hardware button slowly until the light turns blue ( it usually starts working on the 3rd time ), rather rudimentary solution.

using rfkill has also worked for me when the hardware button absolutely would not work in previous versions of linux mint see http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1287

I'm currently connect to a working wifi and this is my readout:

```
$ iwconfig

eth0  no wireless extensions.


lo    no wireless extensions.


wlan0 IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"openWiFi"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: xx:BF:EA:EE:8D:04   
      Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power=27 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:131   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Button doesn't do anything and my rfkill list does say my phy0 hard is blocked. however, unblock cmd doesn't fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you switch from windows and if you turn off your WIFI in windows it will not show in ubuntu. This is problem comes in dual boot. So check if your WIFI adapter is turned on in Windows and then reboot in ubuntu. Also updating ubuntu may help.

Comment: i have found this in other forums and this did not fix the problem. I have also updated Ubuntu already.